# There is any guide to migrate Cocos2d-x 2.1.5 to 2.2.4?

Tags: migration, cocos2d-x

I don't wanna rewrite all the code of my iOS/Android game I just wanna try to upgrade the Cocos' version but i have no found any guide for that, only for new projects, not for big ones like mine.

Any helpful doc in the net?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Note that the basic upgrade procedure is: 1) delete cocos2d files, move new files in place, update project with new and deleted files or if that doesn't work (usually when the changes are too significant or the cocos2d structure has changed) 2) create a new, empty project with the newer cocos2d-x version, add your existing source files and resources into that project, and re-apply any of your project-specific build and other settings. In both cases you'll have to manually update your code to match any changes in the cocos2d API.

Comment: Thankyou and sorry I didn't understand that this is not the right question in this place. But I have an error that can't spot on Android and this upgrade probably fix it.